# Scrolling in windbg line by line

Tags: user-interface, windbg

Is there any way to make windbg scroll disassembly line by line with mouse or scroll bars but not by commands?
It's quite difficult to don't lost current code line with scrolling per page.

Comment: You want to control the console output or just want to step instruction by instruction? I don't think you can control the console output in this manner, you can step through the instructions using F9, F10, F11 keys same as Visual Studio C++, also here is a link to shortcut keys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551913(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Console already have a scroll bar. And, as I said early, I don't want to control scrolling with commands, hotkeys and keyboard at all. I need to scroll disassembly window line by line just like everyone can scroll code in IDE. Or at least by two or three lines but not by pages. This is not even for debugging, I just want to read crash dumps with comfort.

Comment: Click on the arrow icon at the top of the scrollbar to scroll up 1 line or at the bottom of the scrollbar to scroll down 1 line. Works fine here in WinDbg 6.2.9200.

Comment: @cassandradied: Which version of WinDbg are you using on which OS?

Comment: @ThomasW, latest(86, 64)/Win7 (64).